# What does "carry the twosie" mean in here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is a dialogue from the TV series *Jessie*, episode title is *The Fear In Our Stars*.

> -So, the asteroid's not gonna hit Earth?

> -Hardly. Look, if you multiply the trajectory of the asteroid by the angle of Earth's rotation, **carry the twosie**, The asteroid is actually going to...  Crash right into Central Park!

I have no idea what the speaker means here.

Answer (score 6):

"Twosie" is a diminutive of "two"; compare [onesie-twosie](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/onesie-twosie), an idiom meaning in ones and twos, or "twosie" a type of [sleepwear in two pieces](https://www.amazon.co.uk/twosie/s?k=twosie). This is by analogy with "[onesie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onesie)" which is a better-known word for a single-piece garment originally for small children (hence the diminutive) and now used as sleep/leisure wear by adults.

"Carry the two" is an example of a procedure in arithmetic where you do multiplication (or addition) digit by digit, carrying the excess over to the next column: [see this explanation on WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Do-Long-Multiplication).

So "carry the twosie" is a childish way of doing multiplication, presumably intended for humorous effect.

Comment: The whole statement is nonsense math, *twosie* just underlines that.